# Textbox to filter datasheet (finds matching records with each keystroke you type) in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Can someone help me understand why this code isn't producing expected results?
I have a form with a text box called TxtVendorSearch.

When a user begins typing into this text box, I'd like for it to start filtering the results in the form's subdatasheet.

I am starting with a fully populated datasheet, and I'm not sure why the filter blanks out the whole thing as soon as I start typing a valid filter that should leave results.

```
Private Sub TxtVendorSearch_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)

Dim str1 As String

str1 = "[VendorID] LIKE '*" & Me.TxtVendorSearch.Value & "*' "


Me!subOrderDS1.Form.Filter = str1
Me!subOrderDS1.Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Try removing the trailing space "*' "

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and i searched the internet for the keyword "find as you type" AND "ms access"

i found this [great article](http://allenbrowne.com/appfindasutype.html). hopefully it will solve your problem.

N.B. this article also contains the source code to use.

Comment: Dead link.  Looks like the capitalization changed in the URL; try http://allenbrowne.com/AppFindAsUType.html instead.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the `KeyPress` event, you're not going to be able to easily reconstruct the actual input data from within the event handler itself (when the event is triggered, the key just pressed is not yet added to the text of the textbox, meaning you're always short a the last keystroke).

Instead, use the `KeyDown` event, and use the textbox' `.Text` property instead of `.Value`.
`.Value` is only set once the focus has moved away from the box.

So your code can be simply rewritten as (make sure your KeyDown event is set in the textbox's events on the form):

```vb
Private Sub TxtVendorSearch_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    ' If there is no filter criteria, disable filtering '
    If Len(Trim(TxtVendorSearch.Text)) = 0 Then 
       subOrderDS1.Form.FilterOn = False
       Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Do nothing if user hits RETURN or TAB '
    If KeyAscii < 32 Then
       KeyCode = 0
       Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim str1 As String

    str1 = "[VendorID] LIKE '*" & Trim$(TxtVendorSearch.Text) & "*'"

    subOrderDS1.Form.Filter = str1
    subOrderDS1.Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

I used `Trim()` to remove any leading and trailing white-space that the user may have typed.

Last thing: you don't need to use `Me.` or `Me!` from within the form's code itself.
Doesn't hurt if you do, but it makes things a bit less legible without adding anything to the code.